# unit testing a static Main() method in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am trying to write unit tests using visual studio unit testing framework for a static Main method, which is also my entry point to my application. I have my method as follows.

```
public static void Main()
        {
            StructureMapBootstrapper.Register();
            SetupFilter<Applicant>();
        }
```

and this calls a generic SetupFilter method

```
private static void SetupFilter<T>() where T : IDataFilterBase, new()
        {
            var filterName = typeof(T).Name;
            if ("StartReceiver".TryGetTrueOrFalseConfigValue(filterName))
            {
                ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<IDataFilterBase>().Use<T>());
                var filter = new T();
                filter.StartReceiver();
                LogHelper.LogInfo(string.Format("Started {0} Filter Service", filterName));
            }
            else
            {
                LogHelper.LogInfo(string.Format("{0} Filter Service NOT started. StartReceiver flag is set to false", filterName));
            }
        }
```

First thing that came to my mind is to use MOQ and verify that SetupFilter method was called at least once but the compiler complained on the method being static.
Any idea on how to write a test for this method? How do I set it up using VS-unit testing framework and what do I need to Assert?

Comment: You're attempting to unit test your IoC container? And what's that crazy extension method on strings for?

Comment: How are you going to unit test private method?

Comment: IMHO you should not unit test Main - you might be able to unit test what `Main` _does_ but a _true_ unit test would require you to mock out the `Register` and `SetupFilter` methods, and just verify that `Main` calls those two methods, which is probably not what you're wanting to do.

Comment: IMO, it doesn't make any sense to unit test the Main method.  Normally,  when you unit test a method, you are testing one of two things:  1. It's return value, or 2. something it did to the state of the application.  In this case, you are not setting a return value of Main, and the state perishes with the exit of Main.

Comment: What does your existing test look like?

Comment: @DStanley tell me more on your idea. My understanding is you can MOQ  the class and not the method. Also, as mentioned in my original post the reason I can't use MOQ is that the compiler complains about "static types cannot be used as type arguments". Because when you MOQ you instantiate a new class and a static class cannot be instantiated...

Comment: I'm not sure what class you're talking about, but yes you cannot mock static methods )(or classes) because they are bound at compile-time.  You can certainly _test_ `SetupFilter` directly, but I don't see the point of _unit_ testing your startup method - that should be done as part of integration testing.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you have to do a small refactor of your code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()   
    {
       (new MyClass()).run();
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        StructureMapBootstrapper.Register();
        SetupFilter<Applicant>();
    }
}
```

Then you can test normal method instead of `static`

Comment: I believe the ops problem is actually linked to `SetupFilter` being static... not Main.  You've fixed the wrong problem.